# Web based voice sign in

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, voice-recognition

Is there is any way to do a sign in with user voice instead of the regular username and password in web application?

I do that because the client want to make the password useless even for the system developers and he is worrying about that the developer know the username and password for the user when he logged in and then can log that and abuse it.

i suggested to implement it by a security token that sent to his mobile when the user enter his username and password and then enter the token to complete the log in process.

But i face a problem that may be the SMS take a while from 1 to 40 sec to reach the user's mobile.

**So, i thought about the voice login.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The developers don't need the username and password if they're the ones building the application in the first place.

Comment: If your client can't trust you, you need to find a new client.

Comment: Thank you all for quick reply, we use active directory as a repo for the user data and we have more than one system(in house and 3rd parties) and all use the active directory same username and password to login so if in some system the developer implement a simple log then he can access the other systems .... and this is the problem.

Comment: Seems like your client needs to discuss this with their IT, rather than having developers cobble up something they shouldn't in the first place. IMHO, with AD in place, IT can grant the stakeholder for your project in your client's organization whatever access/restrictions they want in place. In other words, the "issue" isn't something for developers to "fix"....